# Limiting result sets by future date - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

The Query below produces a record for each Entry in the SP_ScheduleEvent Table.

```
 SELECT m.MaterialId,  m.MaterialTitle, se.EventDateTime, c.ChannelName
    FROM GB_Material m
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SP_ScheduleEvent se on se.MaterialName = m.MaterialName
    INNER JOIN SP_Schedule s on s.ScheduleID = se.ScheduleID
    INNER JOIN GB_Channel c on c.ChannelID = s.ChannelID
    WHERE LOWER(m.MaterialName) like '%foo%' OR LOWER(m.MaterialTitle) like '%foo%'
```

[image]

I want to limit the result set by the nearest future EventDateTime.

So per material name i would like to see one EventDateTime, which should be the nearest future date to the current time.

And lastly, a record may not exist in the SP_ScheduleEvent table for a particular materialname, in which case there should be null returned for the EventDateTime column

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2d5e)

How would i go about doing this?

Comment: Why are there two `SELECT` clauses?

Comment: Oops! Copy Paste Error

Comment: Your question is vague and ambiguous.  You need to add sample data, desired results, and a SQL Fiddle would help.

Comment: Edited: Is that better?

Comment: I'd never heard of SQL fiddle until now. Cheers.

Comment: @MrBliz **http://sqlfiddle.com** Share the link of your fiddle once you have added sample data and built the schema.

Comment: Updated answer with Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

First, your `LEFT JOIN` is immaterial, because the subsequent joins make it an `INNER JOIN`.  Either use `LEFT JOIN` throughout the `FROM` statement or switch to `INNER JOIN`.

I think you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT m.MaterialId, m.MaterialName, m.MaterialTitle, se.EventDateTime, 
             ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY m.MaterialId OVER se.EventDateTime DESC) as seqnum
      FROM GB_Material m INNER JOIN
           SP_ScheduleEvent se
           on se.MaterialName = m.MaterialName INNER JOIN
           SP_Schedule s
           on s.ScheduleID = se.ScheduleID INNER JOIN
           GB_Channel c
           on c.ChannelID = s.ChannelID
      WHERE se.EventDateTime > getdate() AND
          (LOWER(m.MaterialName) like '%foo%' OR LOWER(m.MaterialTitle) like '%foo%')
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY se.EventDateTime;
```

Comment: Perhaps i should have been clearer in the question. I want to get all Materialnames, but only one EventDateTime. Right now i get all materials and all EventDateTimes.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'.

Comment: I could be wrong, but in the OP's query it appears to me that the outer join is still valid.  The following joins are inner, but they are only joined on `se` and each other.  Since they never cross the outer join to `m`, the outer join should still be preserved.

Comment: @RBarryYoung . . . They join on `se` (or on fields dependent on a field in `se`).  If there is no match in that table, then the `se` column(s) are `null` and the joins fail.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ROW_NUMBER() function:

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT m.MaterialId,  m.MaterialTitle, se.EventDateTime, c.ChannelName,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.MaterialId ORDER BY EventDateTime ASC) AS rn
    FROM GB_Material m
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SP_ScheduleEvent se on se.MaterialName = m.MaterialName
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SP_Schedule s on s.ScheduleID = se.ScheduleID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN GB_Channel c on c.ChannelID = s.ChannelID
    WHERE LOWER(m.MaterialName) like '%foo%' OR LOWER(m.MaterialTitle) like '%foo%'
    AND se.EventDateTime > GETDATE()
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE rn=1
```

Comment: Thanks, I Realised i needed one extra specification, regarding what to do if there is no record in the SP_ScheduleEvent table. Updated the question

Comment: Modified answer with all LOJ's to return NULL when there is no entry in SP_ScheduleEvent.

Comment: They both produce the same results